# "Island Paradise" achievement in Fable 3

Tags: achievements, fable-3

To get the "Island Paradise" achievement in Fable 3, I need to establish the island of Driftwood. Far as I can tell, this involves a quest chain, but I can't find where I left off.

I've read that the first quest is "Restoration" that involves giving money to a guy in Millfields to rebuild a bridge and then I need to return to the same place to cross that bridge and get to Driftwood for the next set of quests.

I vaguely recall paying the bridge builder, but I have absolutely no idea where that was. Running around Millfields isn't helping. I see the island on my map in the sanctuary and it has an exclamation mark over it. How do I get there? Is it still achievable now that I'm the ruler of Albion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

